# PHP - Finding FFT of an array

Tags: php, fft

I have an homework and I need to find first interpolation and then fft of an array. I found interpolation but I couldn't find how to do fft. I searched a lot but I'm a begginer about php. Is there anyone who can help me or show me a way with it ?

My Code:

```
<?php
echo " ".'<br>'.'<br>';
$arr=array(800,850,800,750,950,1100,950,950,850);

$x = array();
$y = array();
$running_total = 0;


for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){

    $y[$i] = $arr[$i];
    $running_total += $arr[$i];
    $x[$i] = $running_total;

}


$arrgraph = array_combine($y, $x);


$d = array();
for ($i=0 ; $i < count($arr)  ; $i++ ) { 

    $d[$i]=1000*$i;

}

$int = array();

for ($i=0; $i < count($arr); $i++) { 

    $int[$i] = $y[$i]+($y[$i+1]-$y[$i])*($d[$i]-$x[$i])/($x[$i+1]-$x[$i]);

}
```

I need to find fft of $int array. Thanks.

Comment: I have no clue what you mean by "find fft of $int array", but what keeps you from writing some code that helps you to find that?

Comment: Did you google for `FFT PHP`? https://gist.github.com/mbijon/1332348

Comment: or another prominent hit on google: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21966265/compute-fft-in-php-for-array-of-numbers

Comment: Thank you all, all I wanted is sources, sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: https://www.phpclasses.org/package/6193-PHP-Compute-the-Fast-Fourier-Transform-of-sampled-data.html